# Rails using Sidekiq on Heroku - Error while trying to deserialize arguments: uninitialized constant Order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, shopify, sidekiq

```
WARN: ActiveJob::DeserializationError: Error while trying to deserialize arguments: uninitialized constant Order
```

Today I started getting this error today. I have changed NO code at all, but every webhook I receive from Shopify is getting hit with this error. I don't understand why I would start getting this error today, if nothing has changed.

On top of that, I don't have or ever call for a constant "Order"

Not too sure what is going on, so hopefully somebody here can help shed some light. I have a model called ShopifyOrder that I do use in the job being called from this webhook.

Comment: Is it possible that a long queue could cause something like this? I just don't understand where it is getting the constant "Order"

Comment: please add some more details related to your error logs

Answer (score 0):

You can use this reference for more issue related to deserializing: https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app/issues/600

So here, you can create global_id.rb in config/initializers/global_id.rb

```
GlobalID::Locator.use :shopify do |gid|
end

Order = Class.new
```

Let me know if you need anything from me.

Thanks